# Proper Android Intent Helper Class Usage?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two classes a **MainActivity.class** and a **IntentsUtils.class**.

Here is my **IntentsUtils.class**:

```
 public class IntentsUtils
    {
        public void invokeWebBrowser(Activity activity)
        {
            String url = "http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

If I wanted to run invokeWebBrowser() from my **MainActivity.class**, what would be the best method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launch_br_btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick() {
     IntentUtils.invokeWebBrowser(MainActivity.this);
  }

})
```

put this to your `onCreate()` method of MainActivity.

Comment: Just a note, `invokeWebBrowser` would have to be `static` in this example.